# QFormLayout drops the label text when using setItem

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

Using below code to add Items into QFormLayout, but nothing displayed and yet no any error logs can be found.

```
fl1 = QFormLayout()
label = QLabel()
label.setText("HELLO")
item1 = QWidgetItem(label)
fl1.setItem(1, 0, item1)
item2 = QWidgetItem(QLineEdit())
fl1.setItem(1, 1, item2)
fl1.update()
fl1.invalidate()
```

Per the pyqt doc, I didn't yet find any specific note about setItem:

> QFormLayout.setItem (self, int row, ItemRole role, QLayoutItem item)
>
> The item argument has it's ownership transferred to Qt.
>
> Sets the item in the given row for the given role to item, extending the layout with empty rows if necessary.
>
> If the cell is already occupied, the item is not inserted and an error message is sent to the console. The item spans both columns.
>
> Warning: Do not use this function to add child layouts or child widget items. Use setLayout() or setWidget() instead.
>
> See also setLayout().

Please share any comments will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using QWidgetItem shouldn't be necessary at all, try inserting the labels and line edits directly

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I knew it would be working once using QFormLayout.addRow/setWidget, what I want to know is how I can make it working under this limited condition and why this API doesn't behavior as expected.